# parsing json data from C# List

Tags: c#, wcf, json

I am calling a WCF service that is bundling the data into a List with a type String.

The data being returned from the service in json when I do a consol.log(response.d):

"ABC 100"

What I would like to do is be able to reference each value by name or index.  Can I use a List object and reference the data by index/name?  If so, how?  If not, what are my options?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes use a list and this can be usefull[Convert objects to JSON in C# using JavaScriptSerializer](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pini_dayan/archive/2009/03/12/convert-objects-to-json-in-c-using-javascriptserializer.aspx)

Comment: This wound up being exactly what I needed to do.  I was passing in a List<String> which didn't give me the flexibility of calling it by name or index.  I had to create an object to pass in my data elements and then build the list of that object which I then serialized to JSON

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a bit more detail about the input data? Is it all as a single string or as a list of strings?

Either way, I am guessing what you are looking for is an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx)

This will let you reference data both on the index and a name/hash, which I presume is the challenging part of your question, not the splitting of the JSON string into the required data structure.